# Memory use of multiple identical literals vs const

Tags: c, memory, constants, literals

In C, in terms of the amount of memory used, if there are a bunch of functions all with `return 1;`, is each `1` literal stored or just one `1`?

I.E. would it be better to use (at file scope) `static const int numOne = 1` and then have the functions use `return numOne;`?

In case it is compiler dependent, I am compiling for a TI MCU using TI's C28x compiler.

Please note this question is about C *not* C++.

Comment: literals have no storage in data memory. they will be embedded in the code. they might be present in registers. i think thats also the reason you cant take the address of a literal(string literal is exception)

Comment: I guess all my string literals are what is clogging up my .econst section then :)

Comment: how much ram does your controller have? since in contrller there are no heap section and its all about ram and flash. i think string literals will be stored in flash..not sure.

Comment: its better if you ask this question in ti's e2e or http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, usually literals aren't "stored" at all. In particular small integer constants as this one usually go into immediates for the assembler, they are directly in the code, not in some data section.

Comment: Loaded up the device and checked the disassembly, `MOVB AL, #0x0`. Thanks